# Структура БД

Tags: php, mysql

Как реализовать такую структуру?

```
Таблица_Язык
id   название
1    РУС
2    УКР
3    АНГ

Таблица_Новости
id   язык_id   текст
1    2         новость на украинском
2    3         новость на английском
3    1         новость на русском
```

Я так понял, в таблице **Таблица_Новости** повторяющийся ключ **id**?
Если новость на 3-х языках:

```
id   язык_id   текст
1       1      Привет
1       2      Привiт
1       3      Hello
```

Если не повторяются (**id** = 1,2,3), как показано выше, то мне выбирать **IN(id,id+1,id+2)**?
Чтобы выбрать одну новость на 3-х языках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, либо первичный ключ по двум колонкам (если id - это id новости, а не строки), либо разбить на две таблицы.

Comment: Да, в одной таблице языки, в другой новости на 3-х языках, то есть ключ одинаковый, не уникальный, спасибо.